# JBoss 7.4 ActiveMQ Artemis Queue Can't binding to a specific JNDI name

Tags: java, jndi, activemq-artemis, hornetq, jboss-eap-7

I'm working on a JBoss migration from EAP 6.4 to 7.4.
One of the issues found is the replacement of HornetQ with ActiveMQ Artemis version 2.16.0.redhat-00022. My issue in specific is the JNDI binding for the created queues.

On HornetQ the following code was used to create the queue:

```
import org.hornetq.api.jms.management.JMSServerControl;
...
...
JMSServerControl srv_c = getJMSServerControl(); // this method gets the object from MBServer
srv.createQueue("MyQName", "queue/MyQName", null, false);
```

In the other part of the code, I'm able to search the queue via JNDI name:

```java
import javax.jms.Queue;
...
...
ctx = new InitialContext();
Queue ourQueue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("queue/MyQName");
if(ourQueue == null) {
  log.error("Queue not found!");
} else {
  log.info("Queue found");
}
```

Looking for an equivalent on Artemis I tried to use **ActiveMQServerControl** and specify the configuration for the queue creation.

```
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.ActiveMQServerControl;
...
...
ActiveMQServerControl srv_c = getJMSServerControl(); // also found via MBServer
String queueConfig = "{" +
  "\"name\": \"MyQName\"," +
  "\"address\": \"jms.queue.MyQName\"," +
  "\"durable\": false," +
  "\"entries\": [\"java:/queue/MyQName\"]" +
  "}";
srv_c.createQueue(queueConfig);
```

However, when I try to find the queue via JNDI it always returns that the object doesn't exist. Across the system the queues are retrieved via JNDI which is why I need to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you're passing to [`ActiveMQServerControl.createQueue`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#createQueue(java.lang.String)) contains "entries" which is not valid. See the JavaDoc for [`QueueConfiguration`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/QueueConfiguration.html) for details on what properties are valid.

That said, you almost certainly should be using one of the [WildFly Management Clients](https://docs.wildfly.org/23/Admin_Guide.html#Management_Clients) instead of trying to work directly with the embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis. By using WildFly management you'll have access to a rich model, including all the necessary JMS related operations (including [adding a queue](https://docs.wildfly.org/23/wildscribe/subsystem/messaging-activemq/server/jms-queue/index.html#op-add)). Furthermore, those changes will be reflected *in the model* which provides benefits like automatically updating the XML configuration file (e.g. `standalone-full.xml`) on disk.

It's important to note that in this context WildFly itself manages the JNDI entries, not ActiveMQ Artemis. That's why when you look up JMS admin objects in WildFly you use `org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory` rather than a class from ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: I can't agree more than what Justin wrote: you would need to register the queue with Wildfly JNDI store if you want to be able to access it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and the queue creation configuration correction. However, I understand that the WildFly Management Client would be used if it knew the name and number of queues needed. I used "MyQName" to simplify the case, but in the real case the queue names are obtained from a database and the name and quantity vary, that's why I need a way to do it in code. Will there be any workaround for what I need to do?

Comment: You _can_ do it in code. You've got a handful of different options available, but if you're using Java then [this class](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/main/cli/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/cli/scriptsupport/CLI.java) is probably the easiest to use.